# Why is the nameserver in “/etc/resolv.conf” not my router IP in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, networking, dns

I am running Mac OS X and I’m using DHCP. I was under the impression that my computer first went to the router to look up an IP address, and so on. So why isn't the router IP address an entry in `/etc/resolv.conf`? Instead, the file contains two IP address that are not even of the form `192.168.1.0`-`255`.

Comment: Apparently these are the DNS servers of my ISP. Since this is a home network, I was expecting my DNS server to actually be my router. I am confused on how a packet is able to go from my computer to the IP address outside my local network. Doesn't it first need to go to the router before this DNS server?

Comment: Yes, checking the DNS settings confirms this. The router brand is Arris.

Comment: "Doesn't it first need to go to the router before this DNS server?" - Yes, it does. Thats what the subnet mask and standard gateway are for.  

Your OS sees, that your DNS servers IP is not within your local network, which is determined from the subnet mask and your local IP which tells it, that it needs to send the physical ethernet packets to the Standard gateway machine, in this case your home router.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is absolutely no requirement for the DNS server(s) specified by DHCP to be the address of the router - and indeed that will only be the case where the router is also acting as a DNS server - which is usually true for small home networks, but often untrue for corporate networks - indeed the larger the network the less likely the DNS servers are related to the router.

DHCP allows for the specification of arbitrary DNS servers - the person that set up the DHCP server simply configured nameservers outside the range you expect. This could be for performance, convenience or other reasons.

In case I've slightly misinterpreted the question or its intent has been obscured by editing - `/etc/resolv.conf` contains information about DNS servers and name resolution.  It says nothing about routing.

Answer (score 4):

Your `/etc/resolv.conf` likely contains what your DHCP server told your computer to use for DNS servers.

Many home gateway routers run a DNS proxy service and thus serve out their own NAT private IP address as a DNS server address, and it sounds like that's what you're accustomed to seeing. However, it isn't really necessary for them to do that, and some home gateways just pass along whichever DNS server addresses *they* were configured (either manually, or dynamically via PPPoA/PPPoE/DHCP/etc.) to use.